# Moving from jruby on rails to ruby on rails and getting error No such file to load -- java (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jrubyonrails

In one of my rails application i tried to use jruby and setup everything accordingly. But later i wanted to use only ruby and then cleaned up.

But the problem is when i am running application in development mode, it's perfectly fine but while trying to deploy in production giving me the following error in ubuntu server [APACHE AND PASSENGER]

I am stuck into this point. Any help is appreciable.

```
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': No such file to load -- java (LoadError)
```

Added Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.6'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'will_paginate',           ' 3.1.0'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', ' 0.0.10'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',          '3.3.6'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem "therubyracer"
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'net-sftp', '~> 2.1', '>= 2.1.2'
gem 'net-ssh', '3.2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem "font-awesome-rails"
gem "nokogiri"
gem 'whenever', :require => false
gem 'bcrypt',  '3.1.11'
gem 'httparty', '~> 0.14.0'
gem 'pg'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.4'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.5'
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.5'
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do

  gem 'spring'
end
group :production do

end
group :test do
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 3.0', require: false
  gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 1.5'
  gem 'faker', '~> 1.6.1'
end
```

Comment: Please add your gemfile. Are you using ruby version manager like rbenv or rvm?

Comment: You should also look at the full stack trace. As `active_support/dependencies` just resolves dependencies and the error might be from somewhere in your application or in your gems.

Comment: @max gem file added. I am not using rvm/rbenv for ubuntu server but using ram in development environment.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the solution and feeling a bit dump at the end.

Though i cleaned up all jruby based gems from the gem file, there was still a module in my library where I imported java library. After cleaning that production fires up.